# How can I query SQL just after transaction open?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, transactions, spring-boot

Just like in the title. I need to query a specific function on database which will define a few values assigned to the transaction. If it's possible I want to make it a global configuration connected with a specific profile(There are few requests that I do not want to load that function).

Project is build on Java SE 1.7, Spring Boot 1.1.7 and it connects with PostgreSQL database.

Requests are build on 3 layers, SomeClassController(Controller), SomeClassService(Service), SomeClassDB(Repository). On SomeClassDB it connects with database using JdbcTemplate from Spring and performs a CRUD operations. Before any of those operations I want to query a function. And as i mentioned it, I don't want a method that will do the job - I need something like global configuration on TransactionManager?

Maybe I should use TransactionSynchronization with beforeCommit method? But I don't know how to use it globally.

EDIT1: What I can but i don't want to ;):

```
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
@Service
public class SessionService {

Boolean flag;

public SessionService(){
    flag=false;
}

@Value("${appVersion}") String appVersion;  
@Value("${appArtifactId}") String appArtifactId;

public void addSession(){
    if(!flag){
        jdbcTemplate.execute("SELECT add_ses('"+appArtifactId+"','"+appVersion+")");
        flag=true;
    }
}

public void deleteSession(){

    jdbcTemplate.execute("SELECT del_ses()");
    }
}
```

And now I can just call those two methods on start and end of 2nd layer class with @Autowired this class. But I really don't want to do it in that way. Someone, someday will forget about it propagating that 2nd layer SomeClassService class and I want to avoid it.

I hope that will get you closer to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This could be typical use case of **aspects**. Have you tried to write an aspect for this? Aspect can be configured to execute some code before and after call of a method in specific package or method decorated by specific annotation. Spring has very nice support for aspects.

Another way is to create a **proxy** (using java.lang.reflect.Proxy) object which will call your initialization code and then delegate to proxied object.